# New line in math mode with two dollars

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Is there a way to got a new line in math mode with two dollars  $$ ... $$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$$` in LaTeX. For multiline display math look at the `amsmath` package.

Comment: If you are using LaTeX instead of plain TeX, there is a way; it's using `\eqalign`, but it's not recommended for a number of reasons.  It's better to use one of the multi-line display structures provided by the `amsmath` package.  Take a look at the user guide (`texdoc amsldoc`); it's not that many pages, and there's a lot more that you might find useful.

Comment: What exactly are you doing since you are using the `$$...$$`? Are you using some sort of online webtool? As you can see from others comments LaTeX users generally do not use the `$$...$$` syntax

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to write multiline equations in plain TeX.  The first is `\eqalign` which aligns equations at the alignment character (`&`) and the second is `\displaylines` which simply centers the equations horizontally.  There is also `\eqalignno` which adds a third column to `\eqalign` where you can put an optional equation number.

```
$$\eqalign{
    a &= b\cr
    c &= d + e\cr
}$$

$$\displaylines{
    a = b\cr
    c = d + e\cr
}$$

\bye
```

[image]